# How can I create an output binding to SignalR Service from Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to implement a real-time chat application. After executing the negotiate function, the client adds a message to a Cosmos collection.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-azure-functions

> 1. A change is made in a Cosmos DB collection
> 2. The change event is propagated to the Cosmos DB change feed
> 3. An Azure Functions is triggered by the change event using the Cosmos DB trigger
> 4. The SignalR Service output binding publishes a message to SignalR Service
> 5. SignalR Service publishes the message to all connected clients

I took care of the first 3 steps, but I'm stuck at step 4. Are there any code samples demonstrating how a SignalR output binding is setup between a trigger and the SignalR service? I'm using C# and ideally would like a sample that uses attributes only (i.e. no json configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Azure SignalR output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service?tabs=csharp#output) like so to connect Cosmos DB Change Feed to SignalR:

```
public static async Task Run(
    [CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "your-monitored-db",
        collectionName: "your-monitored-collection",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosConnectionStringSettingName",
        LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]
        IReadOnlyList<Document> events,
    [SignalR(HubName = "events", ConnectionStringSetting = "SignalRConnectionStringSettingName")] 
        IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
    ILogger log)
{
    await signalRMessages.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage()
    {
        Target = "nameOfTheSignalRHub",
        Arguments = new[] {
            events.Select(singleEvent => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourEventClass>(singleEvent.ToString()))
        }
    });
}
```

Please see [this repo](https://github.com/ealsur/serverlessazurefriday) for a full solution that uses the architecture you are proposing.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me understand bindings better.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example of how to send a message to SignalR from Azure Function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config

Comment: Can you provide the relevant information from the link into your SO answer in case the link goes stale?