# Azure SignalR Blazor app not receiving messages

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-signalr

I'm looking at incorporating Azure SignalR functionality into my .net core Blazor web application. To this end i've been following this tutorial - [Azure Signalr Serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-csharp). This is working fine - i have a project running the Azure functions app and can start up two browsers and have a chat session. What i'm trying to do is add the ability to receive these message notifications from the Azure signalR hub that's been configured into my Blazor app. I've added the following code in Index.razor.cs that mimics the javascript code in the example client:

```
public class IndexComponent : ComponentBase
{
    private HubConnection _connection;

    public string Message;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:7071/api")
            .Build();

        _connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            Message = $"Got message {message} from user {user}";
            this.StateHasChanged();
        });

        _connection.StartAsync();

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

The example javascript code btw is:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(`${apiBaseUrl}/api`)
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build();

connection.on('newMessage', newMessage);
connection.onclose(() => console.log('disconnected'));

console.log('connecting...');
connection.start()
  .then(() => data.ready = true)
  .catch(console.error);
```

So the problem is that my Blazor app never receives any message notifications sent from the javascript chat clients (so the _connection.On handler is never hit). What am i missing in my Blazor code ?

Comment: Blazor Server or WebAssembly?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Blazor Server

Comment: I thought Blazor Server was already connected and running on the code was executed on the server?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I want to connect to a Azure SignalR service, which is what the clients in the example are doing.

Comment: @auburg I think I see.  So instead of connecting backend and using the built in SignalR you want to add a new SignalR connection so the client side can both be connected to the backend and to another SignalR service.  Is that right?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Yes - that's right. The example i've given is a half way house - ultimately i want my blazor client(s) to receive updates from my back end when inserts are made to a  azure hosted sql server via a webapi. For now i just want to hook up to this simpler scenario where the blazor app receives the same messages from a chat azure signalr service.

Comment: @auburg  Just a thought, since you're using SignalR to talk to the server already, would it be easier to add the connection on the server as well and then relay that information to the client in the same format as BlazorServer is doing currently?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII What i'm looking for is an example of a Blazor Web UI app receiving events from a  serverless Azure SignalR service via function bindings - not dissimiliar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59995067/how-can-i-create-an-output-binding-to-signalr-service-from-azure-functions My binding would be different because i want it to be triggered  when there are changes to a SQL database. So assuming such a binding was in place, what would my Blazor code (either client side or server side) be?

Comment: @auburg  So to me, and this may not be the right answer just preference, I would place all of this logic on the Server and relay to the client the same as I do in a typical Blazor Server app.  I believe this would be easier to maintain and scale since you're not running essentially two logical processes for the same view(s).  So IMO, place it all on the server but that doesn't mean using the client is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so this is what i needed to do to get it to work in my Blazor app:

```
_connection.On<object>("newMessage", update =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(update);
            //Message = update;
        });
```

I needed to subscribe to the 'newMessage' target (since that's the JS is sending on) and also the type that's being posted isn't a string but a JObject type which i would need to deserialize to the correct type.

Comment: I've spent two hours trying to understand why my Blazor app wasn't receiving any notification. Just in case anyone else has the same problem I've figured that, using NewtonSoft instead of the default System.Text.Json solved the serialization problem [AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-signalr-project)

Comment: spent a few hours on this today... thanks!!